# Unable to connect .NET Core MVC Web API with SQL Server on Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using .NET Core MVC API (.NET Core 6.0), actually just C# in general.

I need to deploy a .NET API on a linux server. However, it seems to that I can't connect to the SQL Server that is running on the same server.

This is the error from .NET

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> System.Exception: Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server Browser has been started.
> ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (00000001, 11): Resource temporarily unavailable
> at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntryOrAddressesCore(String hostName, Boolean justAddresses, AddressFamily addressFamily, ValueStopwatch stopwatch)

This is the error I get from curl

> {"error":true,"message":"Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server Browser has been started."}

Keep in mind that both the API and the database are on the same server.
I think the problem comes from .NET. I am able to connect to the database on the server using the API locally.

This is the connection string in my `appsettings.json`

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnStr": "Data Source=<PUBLICIP>;Initial Catalog=<DBNAME>;User Id=<USER>;Password=<PASS>;Integrated Security=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False",=
    "lockerConStr": ""
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Things I have tried:

- Changed Data Source to (local) - (doesn't work)
- Added Encrypt= false;Trusted_connection=True; - (doesn't work)
- Connect to the SQL Server from local version of the .NET API (successful)
- Connect to the SQL Server using a python script running from the same server (successful)
- Specified Driver in the connection string (doesn't work)

The python script (not sure if this would help)

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                      'Server=<PUBLICIP>;'
                      'Database=<DBNAME>;'
                      'UID=<USER>;'
                      'PWD=<PWD>;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=no;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
```

Comment: `Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser`? It seems that you're not showing us all of the connection/connectionString details. It's trying to connect to an SQL Server by instance name but there's no SQL Browser service on Linux/Docker-based SQL Servers to provide the necessary SQL Server Resolution Protocol support via udp/1434. In other words, if you're trying to connect to `ServerName\InstanceName` then lose the `\InstanceName` part.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Could you please elaborate on Linux SQL Servers having no SQL Browser service? I am unsure if accessing the server through the public IP is considered connecting to the \InstanceName. Do I need to set up an instance name for the SQL Server ? Currently the connection string is "Data Source=xx.xxx.xx.xxx;..."

Comment: What more would you like to know about [SQL Server Browser service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/sql-server-browser-service?view=sql-server-ver16) and the [\[MC-SQLR\]: SQL Server Resolution Protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/mc-sqlr/1ea6e25f-bff9-4364-ba21-5dc449a601b7) that it implements?

Comment: If it's a Linux server and SQL Server is deployed on the exact same machine (i.e.: physically, not through Docker containers) you could try changing your connection string to use `Data Source=tcp:127.0.0.1,1433;` as per the [SqlConnection.ConnectionString Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the whole project on the server and cloned the git back.

After carefully reading the error, I noticed that it's running using my local connection string (not sure why, I changed the connection string on the server). I also rebuilt the solution and republished it a few times. Not sure what changed.

But I finally got it to work!